# How do I write a recursive function that computes ways to sum to a value in a set of numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm working on a question that is asked me to compute the numbers of ways to sum to a specific value in a set of numbers

```
def ways_to_sum(number, set:{int}) -> int:
    blah, blah
```

Calling

```
ways_to_sum(7,{2,3,5})
```

Would give me

```
2
```

As, first, `5+2`, and then, `2+2+3` sums to seven. The function must be recursive. I did not write the base case as I'm struggling to set it up.

Comment: I don't understand why the inputs you show should give that result. There is no `4` in your set.

Comment: You mean 1st:5+2 not 4+3 ?

Comment: "The function has to be a recursive function" So, do you have any other experience with writing recursive functions? Do you understand why recursion would help you solve this problem? Can you think of a way to break the problem up into smaller problems that look similar?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, that part is typo. I fixed it

Comment: @Alex, I would request you provide the 'non-recursive' code for this, because right now it seems you are asking more than 1 problem - how to get the solution to this problem, and how to get a recursive code. Please provide the solution logic so others can help you write a recursive version of it else it just feels like we are solving your homework :).

Comment: @IoaTzimas. Yes, my bad, I typed it too fast.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do have some basic knowledge for recursion but i think i need to visualize this more, recursive function is hard to visualize.

Comment: Well, let's start with the last question: "Can you think of a way to break the problem up into smaller problems that look similar?"

Comment: @AkshaySehgal it is hard to approach in a recursive way, I'll edit and do this in a non-recursive way first I think

Comment: Exactly. Do solve it for say a specific test case. show the input and expected output and the logic you have used to solve it. And then ask the question "how to recursively solve this". That would be a great question for SO.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think subproblems should be cases such ```number-value == 0 for value in set```?

Comment: Okay, so here's my proposal: consider an arbitrary number in the set. Any given summation *either includes, or does not include* this number, right? So... how do you find the solutions that include the number? How do you find the solutions that do not include the number? Finally: how do you get a base case for this? (Hint: I blindly assumed you could pick an arbitrary number from the set! Is that always true?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel for right now, I can think of is to take ```{2,3,5}``` as an instance, assume I use 2 every time to do the math, I will be continuing doing ```number - 2``` until number either reaches ```0``` or it reaches between ```0 and min({2,3,5})```, if the first case, that means picking all 2 worked, if the second case, that means picking all 2 didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient solution but it should work, the base case of the recursion is when number = 0, the reduction step reduces number by each value in the set of numbers given (I named it values). It traces the sum using the trace dictionary, one easy way to speed it up would be to use dynamic programming and store the traces for 1,2,3,..., number in an array

```
def find_sum(number, values, trace = None):
    if trace == None:
        trace = {}
        for i in values:
            trace[i] = 0
    if number == 0:
        return [trace]
    elif number < 0:
        #not a sum
        return None
    stored_trace = []
    for i in values:
        trace_copy = copy.deepcopy(trace)
        trace_copy[i] += 1
        prev_traces = find_sum(number - i, values, trace_copy)
        if prev_traces == None:
            continue
        for j in prev_traces:
            if j not in stored_trace:
                stored_trace.append(j)
    return (stored_trace)

def function(number, values):
    return len(find_sum(number, values))
```

EDIT:
This should be a dynamic programming solution, which constructs the trace of the number from the traces of the number minus each element in values.

```
def find_sum(number, values, past_traces):
    new_trace = []
    for i in values:
        if number - i < 0:
            #this sum doesn't work
            continue
        if past_traces[number-i] == None:
            find_sum(number - i, values, past_traces)
        for j in past_traces[number - i]:
            curr = copy.deepcopy(j)
            curr[i] += 1
            if curr not in new_trace:
                new_trace.append(curr)
    past_traces[number] = new_trace
    return new_trace

def function(number, values):
    zero_trace = {}
    for i in values:
        zero_trace[i] = 0
    return find_sum(number, values, [[zero_trace]] + [None] * number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a homework task, so instead of code I'll give you a description that should enable you to write your own code. And actually it's a lot easier to solve this problem recursively than iteratively.

#### Assumptions

We assume that the numbers in the set `S` are distinct integers greater than 0. The goal is to write a function `countSubsetSum(target, S)` that, given an integer `target`, returns an integer that is equal to the total number of ways to sum up to `target` (ignoring the order), using only **multiples** of numbers in `S`.

#### Base case

We know that the answer is 0 if the set is empty or if the target is less than or equal to 0:

```
countSubsetSum(target, S) = 0, if target <= 0
countSubsetSum(target, S) = 0, if S is empty
```

#### Inductive case

Otherwise, we go through every element `x` in `S`, and for each element, consider two cases:

1. The number of ways to sum up to `target` only using multiples of numbers in `S\{x}`. Here are we are counting solutions not involving `x`.
2. The number of ways to sum up to `target - k*x` (which may be 0 or negative, in which case we hit the base case) only using multiples of number in `S\{x}`, for `k = 1..Floor(target/x)`. Here we are counting solutions involving multiples of `x`.

We can combine both cases like this:

> The number of ways to sum up to `target - k*x` only using multiples of number in `S\{x}`, for all `k = 0..Floor(target/x)`.

So we get:

```
countSubsetSum(target, S)
  = Sum { countSubsetSum(target - k*x, S\{x}) | for all x in S, for all k from 0 .. Floor(target/x) }
```

or as pseudocode:

```
result := 0;
foreach (x in S)
    for(k:=0; k < target/x; k++)
        result := result + countSubsetSum(target - k*x, S\{x});    
return result;
```

#### Time complexity

The time complexity of this algorithm is at least exponential. Note that we can't expect to do much better than that, since this problem is NP-complete, so assuming P<>NP, there cannot be a polynomial time algorithm.